# Problems with accessing newly created actions

Tags: c++, qt, slot, qmenu, qaction

I'm working on painter like application and i want to add an option of creating new actions in menu to manage subsets of points drawn.
I'm creating new actions like so:

```
    void ImageViewer::on_New_setAct_triggered()
{
    setnumber++;
    newset = new QAction;
    newset->setText(QString("Set_" + QString::number(setnumber)));
    ui->menuSet->insertAction(ui->New_setAct, newset);
}
```

I want some slot to change variables upon clicking newly created action, but don't know how to access those actions. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you connect your newly created action's signal to a slot in `on_New_setAct_triggered` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QAction` has his own [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) you can use them.

For example:

```
connect(newset, &QAction::triggered, this, &ImageViewer::on_newset_triggered);
```

Then use the `on_newset_triggered` slot to handle this action.